# Android: Unable to Dismiss ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog, dismiss

This is how I am creating the PorgressDialog:

```
... progressBarDialog = new ProgressDialog( context );
                  progressBarDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressBarDialog.show(this, "Please Wait", "Updating your GPS coordinates",false,true);


//Trigger GPS service to update coordinates
fg.myOnresume(Name);
fg.dontSendSMS();
//Sets the timer at 30 secs
timer= new Timer();
timer.schedule(new startMapActivity());
}
class startMapActivity extends TimerTask 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            //handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            Log.d("", "StartMapActivty--->>>run()");
            // Dismissing Dialog Box
            if(progressBarDialog.isShowing())
            {
                progressBarDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }
```

So Basically after the the timer finished after 30sec I want to dimiss the Dialog, but it is not working :( Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify UI from non UI thread. Use [handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to do it.

Answer (score 1):

change your code a bit. like:

```
    Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {

        public void run() 
        {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           //dismiss your dialoge here....
        }
    };
```

and you can call this like:

```
  Handler h = new Handler();
  h.postDelayed(r, delayMillis);
```

Comment: ok i just test one more method.. its this: Create your progress dialoge like, progressDialoge p = ProgressDialoge.show(myContextVariable,"title","message"); where myContextVariable is initialized like this in onCreate(): myContextVariable = this; // This "this" is very important; otherwise you will probably get a error... now in handler use .Cancel function to cancel the dialoge.... hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread :
[ProgressDialog dismissal in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745810/progressdialog-dismissal-in-android)