# ProgressDialog.dismiss() does not close in Async Class android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have an inner class that downloads some images from the server. The problem is that the ProgressDialog does not dismiss() onPostExecute() method and don't understand why. 
   I understand that the progress dialog should be shown onPreExecute() method, and the after the code from the doInBackground() finished , in the onPostExecute() method the dialog should be dismiss. Do you have any idea what i am doing wrong here? Thank you.

```
 /**
 * Download images from server
 */
public class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;

    // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // progressDialog.show();
        if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }


    }

    // Things to be done before execution of long running operation.
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog = ProgressDialog
                .show(ImagesActivity.this, getString(R.string.pleasewait),
                        getString(R.string.loading));
    }

    // perform long running operation operation
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        System.out.println("doInBackground loading.." + id);
        String tempPath = FileUtils.createTempFile(id);
        for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.size(); i++) {
            imagePaths.get(i).trim();
            try {
                Bitmap imgTemp;
                imgTemp = FileUtils.downloadBitmapFromURL(id,
                        imagePaths.get(i), tempPath);
                System.out.println("imgTemp: " + imgTemp);
                if (imgTemp != null) {
                    // save image on sdcard.
                    // compress it for performance
                    Bitmap img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imgTemp, 90, 80,
                            true);
                    imgTemp.recycle();
                    FileUtils.saveDataToFile(img, tempPath,
                            imagePaths.get(i));
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        Looper.prepare();
        mDialog.dismiss();
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in
     * progress. 
     */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here and see if this is of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538338/progressdialog-in-asynctask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually what you are trying to do is to access the `UI Thread` from another thread and that is not possible , in your case you are using `AsyncTask` class  enables proper and easy use of the UI thread  without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers. use `onPostExecute(Result)` to access the UI Thread.

so this should work

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

     progressDialog.show();
    if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this same problem for quite a while. Here is how I got it solved, take a look at this part of the documentation:

> A dialog is always created and displayed as a part of an Activity. You
>   should normally create dialogs from within your Activity's
>   onCreateDialog(int) callback method. When you use this callback, the
>   Android system automatically manages the state of each dialog and
>   hooks them to the Activity, effectively making it the "owner" of each
>   dialog
>
> Note: If you decide to create a dialog outside of the onCreateDialog()
>   method, it will not be attached to an Activity. You can, however,
>   attach it to an Activity with setOwnerActivity(Activity).

**from:** http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog

This is an example of what you have to set on **your activity:**

```
  @Override
  protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog)
  {
    //This doesn't do anything
    if (id == DIALOG_PROGRESS_ID) {
      ((ProgressDialog)dialog).setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
  }

  @Override
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
  {
    if (id == DIALOG_PROGRESS_ID) {
      ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
      dialog.setMessage("Loading");
      dialog.setCancelable(false);
      dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
      return dialog;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

You can then call 
`myActivity.showDialog(myActivity.DIALOG_PROGRESS_ID)`, `myActivity.dismissDialog(myActivity.DIALOG_PROGRESS_ID)` from any where as long as you have a reference to your activity instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler and onPostExecute() send the handler msg to dismiss the progress dialog.
You can get help from this link [ProgressDialog dismissal in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745810/progressdialog-dismissal-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine but can you check that control are reaching in Post `onPostExecute()` method I have tried as

```
    package com.alarm.activity;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class AlarmManagerActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //set up main content view
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            new DownloadAsyncTask().execute();
        }

        /**
         * Download images from server
         */
        public class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
            private ProgressDialog mDialog;

            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                // progressDialog.show();
                if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }

            // Things to be done before execution of long running operation.
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AlarmManagerActivity.this, "Hello", "Test");
            }

            // perform long running operation operation
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                //System.out.println("doInBackground loading.." + id);
                /*            String tempPath = FileUtils.createTempFile(id);
                            for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.size(); i++) {
                                imagePaths.get(i).trim();
                                try {
                                    Bitmap imgTemp;
                                    imgTemp = FileUtils.downloadBitmapFromURL(id, imagePaths.get(i), tempPath);
                                    System.out.println("imgTemp: " + imgTemp);
                                    if (imgTemp != null) {
                                        // save image on sdcard.
                                        // compress it for performance
                                        Bitmap img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imgTemp, 90, 80, true);
                                        imgTemp.recycle();
                                        FileUtils.saveDataToFile(img, tempPath, imagePaths.get(i));
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    mDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }

                            Looper.prepare();
                            mDialog.dismiss();*/

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            /*
             * Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in
             * progress. 
             */
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think problem in `doInbackground()` method. I have simply run thread for sleep 5 sec and after control reaches in `post()` method and dissmiss progress dialog.

Comment: It did not enter the if statement from the onPostExecute() method. Now is fixed. Thank you.